# How to create binding for category in GoJS?

Tags: gojs

I am trying to bind node/link `category` property to a custom property in GoJS. Something like the following -

```js
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
                new go.Binding("category", "cat").makeTwoWay(),
                ...
       );
```

But I have not found any example for that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have a Binding of **Node.category**, because Diagrams and Models already cooperate to support your setting the `category` property on the node data object in the model.

If you want to use a different property name, you can set http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html#nodeCategoryProperty to whatever name you prefer. That appears to be "cat" in your case.